# Polynomial basis - two possible ways to solve?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following set is a span of $\mathrm{P}_{3}(x)$, $K = \{ x^3, x^2-x, x-1, 1\}$?

Is it right to say that if we can express $\sum_{i=0}^3a_{i}x^{i}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^3b_{i}\mathrm{k}_{i}$, where $\mathrm{k}_{i} \in K$, and $b_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$. I.e.,  $ \sum_{i=0}^3a_{i}x^{i} = b_{3}x^3 + b_{2}(x^2-x) + b_{1}(x-1) + b_{0}$, hence we can express uniquely $\{ a_{i} \}_{i=1}^3$ with $\{ b_{i} \}_{i=1}^3$. Alternatively, we can form the following matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
clearly the vectors are linearly independent, hence form a basis of $\mathrm{P}_3(x)$.

Are both ways legitimate and equivalent?

Thank you!